# PHP Determining a file based on parameters in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, file

I'm trying to determine a file based on specific parameters. First, I am recursively iterating through a directory structure such as the following:

- C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/XBOX
- C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/PS3
- C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/GBA

Please notice the console game type at the end of the string. Following this, we have the following:

- C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/XBOX/p123.html
- C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/XBOX/r123.html

If you notice in the second section, there is one file that has a p and one that has an r.

My end goal is to determine which files are p* and which are r*, so my regular expression I'd like to be something of the following (pseudo-code)

`/console/p*/`

or

`/console/r*/`

In summary, I need to iterate through the files and know at the end of my function the filename AND the filetype (p or r) without caring about the console type. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like

```
 preg_match('~/([pr])[^/]+$~', $file, $m);
 if($m[1] == 'p') something
 if($m[1] == 'r') something else
```

// edit: although this answers your question directly, this is not the most effective way. Depending upon what you want, you're better off using glob(), as other people suggested, or glob() + preg_grep() or, even better, a database instead of files. Can you tell us more about what're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function will walk through a directory matching all files that meet a given criteria.

```
$files = array();

foreach(glob("C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/*/p*.html") as $filename) {
    $files['p'][] = $filename;
}

foreach(glob("C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/*/r*.html") as $filename) {
    $files['r'][] = $filename;
}
```

This will give you an array looking like this:

```
array (
    p =>  array (
        0 => p123.htm
        1 => p456.htm
    )

    r => array (
        0 => r123.htm
        1 => r456.htm
    )
)
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate through the results, is there? Wouldn't this work just as well?: $files['p'] = glob("C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/*/p*.html");  ...in fact, glob sometimes returns false, which would cause your foreach loops to error out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to get lists of files, distinguished by the first letter of their filename:

Walk the directory tree, get the filename into a variable like $filename.

$files[$filename[0]][] = $filename;

Answer (score 0):

```
glob('C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/*/p*.html');
glob('C:/Users/programmer/Downloads/reviews/*/r*.html');
```

Comment: glob is a great suggestion but it's not going to fit with the scheme of what I was trying to accomplish